# Items that can be used for both halal and haram purposes

Tags: halal-haram

I would like to go into the career of selling website templates. However, as we know there are some websites that are haram. For example, if I sell a store template in which it makes it easier for the consumer to sell their products they may use it to sell halal items and haram items. Am I guilty if the person uses the website template for a haram purpose?

Also, another question, if I would like to sell extravagant items such as new shoe releases and GPU's would that be haram if someone buys it from me.  I just don't want any blame on the day of judgment.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You're selling knives and I brought one. Now, I stabbed someone with that knife and killed
him.

Will you be responsible for that too?
No. You're not.
Whatever I do with that knife I'll be responsible for that.

Make sure you don't use haram things on your templates and items advertisements. (this is your part)

After buying from you, if people do haram things they'll be sinful. (this is their part)

Do not add haram stuff on your part and you'll be safe InshAllah.

Comment: Thank you very much brother/sister for the response.